# Grouping records by user in Admin view

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I would like to get all records with their usernames when signed in as Admin. For that my controller code is as below;

amol361s_controller.rb

```
    def index

        if current_user.admin
          @amol361s = Amol361.all.search(params[:search]).order("created_at ASC")
          @users = User.all.amol361s
        else
          @amol361s = current_user.amol361s.all.search(params[:search]).visible.order("created_at ASC") 
        end

        respond_to do |format|
          format.html
          format.js
        end

    end
```

index.html.erb

```
<tbody id = "kola">              
<% @users.each do |user| %>
<%= user.amol361s.each do |amol361| %>

<tr class="tr-<%= cycle('odd', 'even') %>" id='<%= "tr_#{amol361.id}" %>'>


<% if current_user && current_user.admin %>
<td class="col-1"><%= link_to amol361.date.try(:strftime,'%d/%m/%Y'), edit_amol361_path(amol361) %></td>
<% else %>
<td class="col-1"><%= amol361.date.try(:strftime,'%d/%m/%Y') %></td>
<% end %>

<td class="col-3"><%= span_with_possibly_red_color amol361.description %></td>


<td class="col-1"><%= number_with_precision(amol361.amount, :delimiter => ",", :precision => 2) %></td>

<td class="col-1 neg"><%= number_with_precision(amol361.discount, :delimiter => ",", :precision => 2) %></td>

<td class="col-1 neg"><%= number_with_precision(amol361.paid, :delimiter => ",", :precision => 2) %></td>


<% @balance += amol361.amount.to_f - amol361.discount.to_f - amol361.paid.to_f %>

<% color = @balance >= 0 ? "pos" : "neg" %>

<td class="col-1 <%= color %>"><%= number_with_precision(@balance.abs, :delimiter => ",", :precision => 0) %></td>

<td class="col-1"><%= amol361.delndel %></td>

<td class="col-1"><%= amol361.remark %></td>

<% if current_user && current_user.admin %>
<td class="col-1"><%= link_to "Hide", hide_amol361_path(amol361), method: :put, remote: true, style: "color:#bb7272;" %>
<%= link_to amol361, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }, :class => 'delete_item' do %>
<i class="fa fa-trash" ></i>
<% end %>
</td>
<% end %>

</tr>

<% end %>
<% end %>


</tbody>
```

Right now I am getting the error as **undefined method amol361s' for # User::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00007f5dec19d088**.

So, I am trying to get the records followed by usernames, similar to how we gather records based on month.

[image: myimage.png]

Any suggestions are most welcome.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you can simply eager load user records if the current user is admin, like this:

```
@amol361s = Amol361.includes(:user).search(params[:search]).order("created_at ASC")
```

If you do this, it will be effective to fetch the user data simply by calling association on each member of this relation, like this:

```
# example:
@amol361s.first.user.username # or whatever the name of username column is
```

I'm not sure I understood your question correctly though, cause it's a little bit unclear to me.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I just edited by adding picture for clear understanding.

Comment: Ok, so what you need in admin view is grouping `Amol361` records by user, right?

Comment: So why don't you fetch users including `amol361s` in correct order, and then, in view, do something like `<% @users.each do |user| %>` and inside of it `<%= user.amol361s.each do |amol361| %>`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually I was on vacation so the reason for the late reply. And I tried with the above code in my index view but it throws me the error as "undefined method `amol361s' for #<User::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00007f5de88d0250>" and In my controller I placed the code as "@amol361s = Amol361.all.search(params[:search]).order("created_at ASC")
      and @users = User.all.amol361s" . Waiting for your reply.

Comment: undefined method amol361s' for # User::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00007f5dec19d088.

Comment: Errors says undefined method

Comment: The error you are getting is not caused by the code in this answer.  You'll need to debug that error yourself.