# Calculate and display the balances from bottom to top in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-6.1

In order to display the records in descending order, I used "created_at DESC" and it worked for all the entries of the table, that is for Date column, Particulars column, Debit and Credit columns except for the Balance and it is still calculated and displayed from top to bottom. But I want to calculate and display from bottom to top. This can be seen in the below image.

expenses_controller.rb

class ExpensesController < ApplicationController

```
  def index
     @expenses = Expense.order("created_at DESC")
  end
```

[image]

For better understanding, find the below image of the Bank statement, as I need to achieve the same.

[image: Capture]

index.html.erb

```
<% balance = 0 %>

<div class="container">

    <table style="width:100%">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Date</th>
          <th>Particulars</th>
          <th>Debit</th>
          <th>Credit</th>
          <th>Balance</th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
    
      <tbody>
        <% @expenses.each do |expense| %>
          <tr>
            <td><%= expense.date.strftime('%d/%m/%Y') %></td>
            <td><%= expense.particulars %></td>
            <td class="pos"><%= expense.debit %></td>
            <td class="neg"><%= expense.credit %></td>
            <% balance += expense.debit.to_f-expense.credit.to_f %>
            <% color = balance >= 0 ? "pos" : "neg" %>
            <td class="<%= color %>"><%= number_with_precision(balance.abs, :delimiter => ",", :precision => 0) %></td>
          </tr>
        <% end %>
      </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Any suggestions are most welcome.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `Expense.order("created_at DESC")` means the most recent at the top while I suppose it should be `ASC`. Anyway, I cannot figure out where balance `2500, 1500, 2000` came from in that case. Can you just forget the code and show the logic behind the expected result?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I want to have the most recent ones at the top. And the balances 2500, 1500, 2000 are the expected outputs to be shown in the table.

Comment: I have updated the post for a better understanding by adding the real bank statement. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still don't understand how balance column `[2500, 1500, 2000]` is calculated, but I could argue something from the screenshot.

Basically you are sorting by a column not existing in the model. So, first you need to build that helper column, populate it, then sort by that column.
It should be possible to do it in SQL, but I'm showing in plain Ruby using a Hash as fake database. You can adapt it to your case easily or look for a most efficient way (SQL).

Let's say data are the following:

```
expenses = [{date: 1, narration: :a, debit: 3.0, credit: 0},
            {date: 2, narration: :b, debit: 0.15, credit: 0},
            {date: 3, narration: :c, debit: 75.0, credit: 0}]
```

And the initial balance is:

```
balance = 1434.64
```

Now lets loop the data adding the new field `balance` and sorting at the end of the loop:

```
expenses.each do |h|
  balance += h[:credit] - h[:debit]
  h[:balance] = balance
end.sort!{ |h| h[:balance]}
```

Now your sorted `expenses` are:

```
[
  {:date=>3, :narration=>:a, :debit=>75.0, :credit=>0, :balance=>1356.49}
  {:date=>2, :narration=>:b, :debit=>0.15, :credit=>0, :balance=>1431.49}
  {:date=>1, :narration=>:c, :debit=>3.0, :credit=>0, :balance=>1431.64}
]
```

You can do calculation in the controller, then pass `expenses` to the view and loop without any need of calculation there.

---

For your rails app, you could implement as follow.

Add the temporary field `balance` to your model (no need to add a column to the database) and initialize to value `0`:

```
class Expense < ApplicationRecord
  attr_accessor :balance

  after_initialize :init

  def init
    self.balance = 0
  end
end
```

Do the calculation in controller, I'm using an initial value of `balance`, just to emulate the example:

```
def index
  @expenses = Expense.all

  balance = 1434.64
  @expenses.each do |e|
    balance += e.credit - e.debit
    e.balance = balance
  end

  @expenses = @expenses.sort{ |e| e.balance }    
end
```

Then in your view, just loop:

```
<% @expenses.each do |expense| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= expense.narration %></td>
    <td><%= expense.debit %></td>
    <td><%= expense.credit %></td>
    <td><%= expense.balance %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

If you insert the records as in your example, you should end up with this result:

```
# ["c", "0.0", "75.0", "1356.49"]
# ["b", "0.0", "0.15", "1431.49"]
# ["a", "0.0", "3.0", "1431.64"]
```

Comment: Thanks for great reply. Please look at the code, https://pastebin.com/mkWJVPKk and in that I see that balance is showing nil, do I need to create a balance field in _form.html.erb.

Comment: Did you add `balance` to your model right now? In that case you should update the field each time you save a record. When you modify or delete a record you need to recalculate `balance` and update all the records affected. Reading your question `balance` is not an attribute of the model and my solution is viable. Check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9697041/rails-how-to-set-a-temporary-variable-thats-not-a-database-field

Comment: Yes I have added the balance column to the Expense model through migration. I am not getting it, how do I update the each time to save a record and to recalculate balance.

Comment: I added the Rails implementation, hope now it is clearer.

Comment: Thank you very much for the implementation. And in the Balance column when there is enough balance I have to show it in red color and when the balance becomes less means negative then I have to show it in black color. For Example, if the Previous Balance is 300 and the Debit is 500 that means the company has to pay 200 that will be shown as -200 in the Balance column. What I want is to show if the balance goes to minus something show in Black color without - sign and if the Balance goes to '+' then show that in Red color, How do I do that.

Comment: I tried with this  <% color = balance >= 0 ? "pos" : "neg" %>
<td class="<%= color %>"><%= number_with_precision(expense.balance, :delimiter => ",", :precision => 0) %></td> But not getting the desired result.

Comment: Did my last edit helped solving the point: "Balance and it is still calculated and displayed from top to bottom. But I want to calculate and display from bottom to top."? Please, post a new question for the formatting problem.

Comment: Excellent! Yes, it greatly helped me solving that point. Thank you very much.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57782051/grouping-records-by-user-in-admin-view

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228641/discussion-between-muhammad-yaseen-and-igian).

Answer (score 1):

If you need to order by creation date first and by balance second, you could use

```rb
@expenses = Expense.order('created_at DESC, balance DESC')
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried but getting the same results.

Answer (score 0):

Since you told it to order by `Expense.order('created_at desc')`, then that's what it's doing. If you want to order by balance, you must instead say `Expense.order('balance desc')`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried but not getting the desired result. The middle entry got as expected but the first and last entry is still not getting as expected.